# How to replace text in a QLineEdit while creating only one item in the undo history?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyside, qlineedit

Alternate question phrasing: How do I make `QLineEdit.clear()` skip the undo history?

I've subclassed QLineEdit to take the path of a csv that is dropped onto it:

```py
class QLineEditDragDrop(QtWidgets.QLineEdit):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__()

    def dragEnterEvent(self, event):
        file_path = Path(event.mimeData().urls()[0].toLocalFile())
        if file_path.suffix == ".csv":
            event.accept()
        else:
            tool_tip = "Please provide a .csv file."
            QToolTip.showText(self.mapToGlobal(self.rect().topRight()), tool_tip,
                              self, self.rect(), 1000)
            event.ignore()

    def dropEvent(self, event):
        # Only accept the first selected file in case of multiple input
        file_path = Path(event.mimeData().urls()[0].toLocalFile())
        if file_path.suffix == ".csv":
            event.accept()
            self.setText(str(file_path))
        else:
            event.ignore()
```

By using setText, the event doesn't register in the undo history, and the user can't use Ctrl-Z to get the previous value back.

So I replaced

```py
self.setText(str(file_path))
```

with

```py
self.clear()
self.insert(str(file_path))
```

but this creates *two* events in the undo history, one for the clear and one for the insert, so that the user gets an empty box on the first <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> and has to hit it again to actually get the previous input back.

I also tried using `self.setText('')` instead of `self.clear()`, but this wipes out the undo history entirely.

How can I just have one event in the history?

Answer (score 0):

*n.b: Figured it out while writing the question, hoping this solution helps someone else.*

An imperfect solution is to use `self.selectAll()` in place of `self.clear()`. Since `insert()` will replace any selected text, this replaces all existing text in the box while creating only a single undo event. It does have the side effect of selecting all text in the field when the user uses undo, which I don't consider ideal, but still better than having to hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> twice.